# Is there any way to write a variable expression having more than 4000 characters in a SSIS variable?

Tags: ssis

Can anybody tell me if there is any way to write an expression in variable in SSIS package having more than 4000 characters which is the maximum limit allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there is probably a more performing way of doing this , why the need for such a large expression? 
Ways to reduce this include:

- Move logic to source data (e.g. stored procedure)
- Conditional Splitting the data and
  working with sets , each with its own
  expression logic

Can you give more detail around this.